# Gauging the progress of Rebuild Reporting Database job, and troubleshooting issues

Tags: experience-analytics, reporting

I am using Sitecore 8.1 with Mongo and Lucene indexes.

I rebuilt the Reporting Database before - it never took more than 10 hours. This time, my PC has been running it for more than 3 days straight.

So far, the only odd symptom is the presence of this exception:

```
ERROR Exception in alarm clock event subscriber.
Message: Binary stream '0' does not contain a valid BinaryHeader. 
Possible causes are invalid stream or object version change between serialization and deserialization.
```

Every single minute. Which needs investigating, but surely does not justify a three-fold increase of rebuild time. Is there anything I can do to gauge the progress of the rebuild, and troubleshoot performance?

Comment: Do you see anything on the jobs admin page? (/sitecore/admin/jobs.aspx)

Comment: I have now stopped it - I will restart it this weekend, and will definitely check it.

Comment: Hi, I don't have a jobs admin page (Sitecore 8.1 here). Do I need a plugin or third-party module?

Comment: The jobs admin page was released in Sitecore 8.1 Update-2, so consider upgrading? :) In all seriousness, though, you might be able to download a later version of Sitecore (8.1u2 or 8.1u3) and add the jobs.aspx page to your `/sitecore/admin` folder and it may just work.